# Animação não repete no android api 8

Tags: android, animação

Oi, estou criando um aplicativo simples e eu quero fazer uma luz ficar piscando, então acrescentei o seguinte código:

```
private void flashLight() {
    anim = animate(imgLight).setDuration(speeds[speed]);
    anim.alpha(0f).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

            anim.alpha(1f).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        flashLight();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

O código funciona perfeitamente em dispositivos android api 11 ou mais, mas nas versões abaixo ele não funciona, sendo que animação só executa uma vez. Gostaria que alguém mim ajudasse no meu problema.

Obs: Estou usando a biblioteca [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/)

Desde já Agradeço.

Comment: Silas, porque não usa o `ObjectAnimator` em vez do `ViewPropertyAnimator`? É muito mais fácil usar transições (0 para 1) e ele ainda tem repetição infinita. Não costumo usar a `NineOldAndroids`, mas eu costumo usar o `ObjectAnimator` da API 11. Se quiser posso montar um resposta usando a API 11, acreditando que a migração para o `NineOldAndroids` é fácil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o `ObjectAnimator` é possível fazer essa animação de forma mais simples:

```
ObjectAnimator flashLight = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgLight, View.ALPHA, 0f, 1f);

flashLight.setDuration(speeds[speed]);
flashLight.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);

// Se quiser fazer inverter a animacao ao final,
//flashLight.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);

// Se quiser um Listener para saber quando a animacao se repetiu:
flashLight.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        // Animacao se repetiu...
    }
});

flashLight.start();

// Lembrando que para cancelar ou pausar, e preciso usar essa instancia!
// flashLight.cancel();
// Ou
// flashLight.pause();
```

Comment: Valeu, ajudou muito!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso

```
   AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true); 

    AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    alphaAnimation.setDuration(speeds[speed]);

    animationSet.addAnimation(alphaAnimation);

    imgLight.setAnimation(animationSet);

    alphaAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // Animacao se repetiu...
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // Fim da Animação
        }
    });

    imgLight.startAnimation(animationSet);
```